# Find the name if I know the previous and the next one

Tags: mysql

I have stop table and I am trying to find the name `Aldgate` in the case I know the stop name of the previous one `Acton Town` and the stop name of the next one `Aldgate East`? The id is incremented by one and the name is not unique. How can I get that?

**For example**

```
12.Acton Town
13.Aldgate
14.Aldgate East
15.Apple
16.Acton Town
17.orange
18.banane
19.Aldgate East
20.Aldgate
21.book 
22.Acton Town
23.Aldgate
24.Aldgate East
```

**Code stops table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops
 (stop_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
 name varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
 lat double(10,6) , 
 longi double(10,6) )
```

Comment: Are ids incremental (no gaps)

Comment: Go create an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to select the previous id first.

```
SELECT name 
FROM stops 
WHERE id = 
   (
    SELECT id + 1 
    FROM stops 
    WHERE name = 'Acton Town'
   );
```

Comment: I was thinking too much. And, it came just in 2 lines. Great Mr. Michael.

Comment: @michael: I have tried your query but I am getting `Subquery returns more than 1 row ` I have tried to add DISTINCT but then I got the same error too.

Comment: So Acton Road isn't unique? Are all the names not unique?

Comment: Please provide all the mandatory information when asking a question if you are looking for a helpful answer @TheBook

Comment: Where's Aldgate East in all of this ?!?!

Comment: @Strawberry if the names were unique as how it seemed in the original question, it wouldn't be needed as OP asked for something directly in between of two ids (1,2,3) -> wants to find 2... The question now is totally different